# How many projects shall I list on my resume when applying for internships in AI and machine learning?

Tags: software-industry, resume, internship

Is it a good idea to list every project (that show some advanced knowledge beyond the university course materials) I have done, or shall I list only those published research papers? Or is it better to only list the projects that are closely related to the open position?

PS: I studied math

Comment: Just like anything else you add to your resume, you need to decide whether to add any given item based on how much value it adds. There is no rule for what relevant experience and achievements you should or should not list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that you list what is relevant to the job to which you are applying.  IF the projects demonstrate skills and experience that will give you an advantage, list them.  If they are irrelevant, don't.

The answer to the age-old question of "how long should my resume be" is "as long as it needs to be to get you the interview."

So, to restate it simply.  Evaluate what should be on your resume on a job-by-job basis, then tailor it to the job for which you are applying.